# Create common interface wrapper for two 3rd party classes

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I would like to create a common wrapper class around two classes from a 3rd party library. The two API classes have 99% the same methods but a few have slightly different signatures.

I've looked into proxies, bridges, adaptors, and CRTP but nothing seems to do exactly what I want.

If I owned the API classes then I would have them inherit from a common base class (and use base class pointers throughout the application) but the API is a closed binary.

Here's a rough cut example of what I'm trying to do.  Any suggestions welcome.

```
#include <stdio.h>

class APIClass1 /* cannot modify */
{
public:
    void one() { printf("APIClass1 ONE\n"); }
    void two() { printf("APIClass1 TWO\n"); }
};

class APIClass2 /* cannot modify */
{
public:
    void one()      { printf("APIClass2 ONE\n"); }
    void two(int n) { printf("APIClass2 TWO: %d\n", n); }
};

class MasterClassBC
{
public:
    virtual ~MasterClassBC() {};
    virtual void one() = 0;
    virtual void two() = 0;
    virtual void two(int n) = 0;
};

template <class T>
class MasterClass : public T, public MasterClassBC
{
public:
    typedef T TBase;

    void one() { TBase::one(); }
    void two() { TBase::two(); }

    void two(int n) { TBase::two(n); }

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MasterClassBC *pBc = new MasterClass<APIClass1>;

    pBc->one();
    pBc->two();

    delete pBc;

    pBc = new MasterClass<APIClass2>;

    pBc->one();
    pBc->two(11);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what is your question, but one way to do this is to use `std::variant` for such kind of type erasure.

Comment: As the question says, I want a common wrapper for the two API classes.  Unfortunately, we're using an old C++ version so `std::variant` is not an option.